# ATmega32u4 Timer 3 overflow not functioning

Tags: c

I've run into an issue using an ATmega32u4, where I am successfully able to use timer 1 overflows, but when I try to repurpose the code for timer 3, it doesn't function.

The following code turns an LED (on pin b7) on and off when timer 1 (16 bit) overflows. It works.

```
#include  <avr/io.h>
#include  <avr/interrupt.h>

int main (void) { 

    DDRB |= (1<<7);; //PortB Output 
    PORTB = 0x00; //PortB All LEDs off

    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10) | (1<<CS12); //Set Prescaler to 1024

    TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1); //Enable Timer Overflowinterrupt 
    sei(); //Enable Interrupts 

    while(1); 

    return 0; 
} 

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) 
{ 

    PORTB ^= (1<<7); //toggle LED

}
```

This next code is intended to perform the same functionality using timer 3, but doesn't work.

```
#include  <avr/io.h>
#include  <avr/interrupt.h>

int main (void) { 

    DDRB |= (1<<7);; //PortB Output 
    PORTB = 0x00; 

    TCCR3B |= (1<<CS30) | (1<<CS32); //Set prescaler to 1024

    TIMSK3 |= (1<<TOIE3); //Enable Timer Overflowinterrupt 
    sei(); //Enable Interrupts 

    while(1); 

    return 0; 
} 

ISR(TIMER3_OVF_vect) 
{ 

    PORTB ^= (1<<7);

}
```

This final code block was used to test that timer 3's count value was increasing (no interrupts involved), which it is. (I'm using a different LED in this test)

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main()
{

    // Prescaler of 1024
    TCCR3B |= (1<<CS32)|(1<<CS30);

    // Initialize Counter
    TCNT3 = 0;

    // Initialize LED
    DDRE |= (1 << 6); // LED0

    // Infinite Loop
    while (1)
    {
        // Flash every 0.016 secs
        // COUNTER = 0.016 / (PRE SCALER / CPU FREQ)
        // 250
        if( TCNT3 >= 250 )
        {
            // Toggle LED
            PORTE ^= (1 << 6); // If output use PORT, If input use PIN

            TCNT3 = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From this, I'm assuming that I'm doing something wrong when calling the interrupt, I'm just not sure what

Comment: Are you using LilyPad, Flora or Leonardo?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using LilyPad or Leonardo.

I am assuming from the code above that it's LilyPad.  Change the TCCR3B to 256 and see if it corrects the problem for you.

```
       TCCR3B = 0x0C; // prescaler = 256
```

Comment: I'm not actually using an arduino product at all, its a custom microcontroller. 

I implemented your suggestion, however it did not resolve my issue. The LED still does not operate. In the third code snippet I posted, I actually user timer 3 with the prescale set to 1024, and read the count value TCNT3 (which works as expected and increments). So I'm not sure this is the issue.